# Definition of Data Engineering in Big Data

Tags: bigdata

I fully understand that this question may be closed as it can be more of an opinion than an actual technical question with an objective answer. However I want to ask it in case someone can help and provide a good response. I think it is important to define what you do in a succint way, so here it goes.

**Q: If you are asked, "what's Data Engineering?" what would your definition be?** (Not "what does a Data Engineer do?")

This one came to mind, but does someone have a better one? And I am talking in the context of Hadoop/Big Data

**A:**

> Data engineering is the process of taking Big Data that is stored in
>   either a structured or unstructured format, processing it in batch or
>   real-time, and generating data in a new format that can be used for
>   further consumption, visualization, Machine Learning or Data Science

Answer (score 3):

I would like to share what I think is a definition of Data Engineering related to Big Data:

> Data Engineering supports and provides expertise to elaborate, 
>   contruct, and maintain a Big Data. Data Engineering uses
>   tools, techniques, frameworks and skills that are essential to a good
>   "Data Infrastructure" or "Data Architecture" behind a Big Data.

A good way to define Data Engineering is understanting what a Data Enginer does. Here is a great infographic about: https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/data-engineering-vs-data-science-infographic

Some responsibilities listed includes:

- Develop, construct, teste and maintain architectures;
- Ensure architecture will support the requirements of the business;
- Develop data set process for data modeling, mining and production;
- Recommend ways to improve data reliability, efficiency and quality.